# Flask só atualiza após limpar histórico de navegação

Tags: python, flask

Estou desenvolvendo um site para fins de estudo com o flask, só que estou precisando limpar o histórico do navegador sempre que faço alguma alteração no meu css, estou fazendo isso porque os navegadores (chrome, edge e mozilla já testados) continuam  exibindo a versão anterior do css mesmo que eu reinicie o server do flask.

Estes aqui são meus logs quando atualizo a página sem limpar o histórico:

```
MEUIP**** - - [06/Sep/2019 15:19:51] "[37mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
MEUIP**** - - [06/Sep/2019 15:19:53] "[37mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
MEUIP**** - - [06/Sep/2019 15:19:56] "[37mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
```

Esses são os logs quando eu limpo o histórico:

```
MEUIP**** - - [06/Sep/2019 15:20:09] "[37mGET /static/css/home.css HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
MEUIP**** - - [06/Sep/2019 15:20:09] "[37mGET /static/images/web_icon.png HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
```

O que eu notei é que a aplicação só vai atrás dos meus arquivos estáticos quando eu limpo o histórico do navegador, creio que esse problema esteja relacionado ao flask sendo mais especifico ainda o problema está na forma como eu estou utilizando o flask, segue meu código na esperança de encontrar uma solução para o problema :

home.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=minhaporta, debug=True)
```

home.html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Image Lab</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="{{url_for('static', filename='images/web_icon.png')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/home.css')}}">
    <h1>Image Lab</h1>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Homea</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Teste</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://google.com">Teste2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

home.css:

```
h1 { font-size: 80px; text-align: center; }
ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 500; padding: 20; }
li { display: inline;}
```

Obs: Só estou tendo esse problema com os arquivos estáticos as outras partes do código estão sendo atualizadas imediatamente sem a necessidade de limpar o histórico.

Comment: Tentei replicar o teu erro mas sem sucesso, verifique com um outro navegador ou faça as requisições diretamente via cURL para ver se o erro persiste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não chega a ser a solução mas foi o suficiente para contornar o meu problema, atualizar a pagina com:

**SHIFT+F5**.